# how to parse a decimal value from JSON response

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing

My json response has an amount value like "20.0000"

Am parsing it like

```
id jsonObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData7 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
AmountArray = [jsonObject1 valueForKey:@"Amt"];
```

My issue is, when i print(to check) jsonObject1, the amount value is just '20' and not '20.0000'. but the actual value from the webservice is '20.0000'. how to parse it correctly?

Comment: `20` and `20.0000` are identical numbers.

Comment: Is the value quoted or not?

Comment: @borrrden : No.. I printed jsonObject1 in NSlog. the amount value is not quoted..

Comment: I mean the *original* JSON (responseData7)

Comment: when i print responseData7, it prints a hexadecimal value.

Comment: @ManojEllappan: Show the output of `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData7 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])`

Comment: {"AT":null,"DId":0,"EMs":null,"Em":null,"LGT":null,"OS":null,"PWD":null,"SId":0,"Sku":null,"UId":627,"UN":null,"AccId":13768,"AccN":0,"Amt":20.0000,"AtF":null,"AtFp":null,"AtN":null,"DExpId":0,"ExpDetLst":null,"ExpDt":"1\/18\/2014","ExpId":31947,"ImgPt":null,"IsSp":false,"Me":null,"ORptEId":0,"PAmt":20.0000,"PAmt2":0.0000,"PAmt3":0.0000,"PF":"UnitWise","PF2":null,"PF3":null,"PId":754,"PT":"CREDITCARD","PT2":null,"PT3":null,"PTId":197,"PTId2":0,"PTId3":0,"RN":null,"RN2":null,"RN3":null}

Comment: If amt is 20.00001, then I think it should work as you expect. Just grab the the doubleValue of the item and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The JSON format (compare http://json.org) distinguishes between
*strings* and *numbers*. Strings are enclosed in quotation marks, for example

```
"Hello world"
"20.0000"
"20"
```

Numbers are not enclosed in quotation marks, for example

```
20.0000
20
```

Now `"20.0000"` and `"20"` are completely different strings, but `20.0000` and `20`
are the ***same real number***.

JSON numbers are converted to `NSNumber` (or `NSDecimalNumber`). But it does not matter
how this number is written in the JSON, this is the same number. It does not make
sense to say

> the actual value from the webservice is '20.0000'

because the value from the web service is the real number `20`, no matter how that number
is written.

If you have to distinguish between `20` and `20.0000` for any reason, then the web service
must write the values as *string* (enclosed in quotation marks).

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` instead of `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`. The proper documentation can be found at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Let me know if it helped you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the double value:

```
 id jsonObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData7 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
 AmountArray = [[jsonObject1 valueForKey:@"Amt"] doubleValue];
```

Comment: Don't you mean doubleValue instead of intValue?